# how to match the iframe text, then skip and match another string in wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, iframe, advanced-custom-fields

I have this iframe code that I want to match for both the  text right in the beginning of the string and continue with the code to find the "soundcloud" text:

```
<iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/297769462&amp;color=%23ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;show_teaser=true" width="100%" height="166" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

My regex, which is: `(<iframe.*?><\/iframe>)`, which tries to match the iframe and anything in between.

What I want is the  + skip everything in between until it finds **soundcloud**.  If both conditions are fulfilled, then it's a match.

Any help would be great thank you.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the question. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`(?i)<iframe(?=((?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\s(src\s*=\s*(['"])(?:(?!\3)[\S\s])*?soundcloud(?:(?!\3)[\S\s])*\3)(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>))\1\s*</iframe\s*>`

https://regex101.com/r/KkJH6x/1

Formatted

```
 (?i)                              # Case insensitive modifier
 < iframe                          # The iframe tag
 (?=                               # Asserttion (a pseudo atomic group)
      (                                 # (1 start)
           (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
           \s 
           (                                 # (2 start), src  attribute with 'soundcloud' in value
                src \s* = \s* 
                ( ['"] )                          # (3), Quote
                (?:
                     (?! \3 )
                     [\S\s] 
                )*?
                soundcloud                        # 'Soundcloud'
                (?:
                     (?! \3 )
                     [\S\s] 
                )*
                \3                                # Close quote
           )                                 # (2 end)

           # The remainder of the tag parts
           (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+
           > 
      )                                 # (1 end)
 )
 \1 
 \s* 
 </iframe \s* >
```